# Is that possible that trace operator may imply strong convergance?

Tags: functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, partial-differential-equations, hilbert-spaces, weak-convergence

Let $V=L^2(\Omega, \mathbb{R}^d)$ and $\mathcal{V}=L^2(0,T,V)$. Suppose that 
$$v_n\to v\qquad \text{weakly in}\quad \mathcal{V}.$$
Let $\gamma:\mathcal{V}\to L^2(0,T,L^2(\Gamma, \mathbb{R^d}))$. Can we deduce (at least for a subsequance) that 
$$\gamma v_n\to \gamma v\qquad \text{in}\quad L^2(0,T,L^2(\Gamma, \mathbb{R^d}))?$$

Comment: I assume there are some other conditions on $\gamma$ that you forgot?

Comment: I only know that $\gamma$ is a trace operator, so it is linear and continuous.

Comment: I don' think $\gamma$ is well defined on $\mathcal{V}$.

Comment: How it should be defined then?

Comment: Presumably $\Gamma$ is the boundary of $\Omega$? There is no reasonable trace operator from $L^2(\Omega)$ to $L^2(\Gamma)$, and the presence of time variable does not change that. Now, it's possible that your $v$  solves some PDE that implies additional regularity for it, which makes it possible to have a trace operator for it... but none of that is in the question.